# Average from Highest to lowest

Tags: python

I needed to create a code for a quiz for students and it has been done successfully.
Now, I had to create a code where a user had to register himself as a student or a teacher(working on a teacher site) and basically a teacher have an option to choose to manipulate students results from the quiz (results are stored in an Excel File). I've done Alphabetical, Highest to lowest, average. Now the teacher is asking me to do Average from highest to lowest!

Here is my code for Average and I want to add from highest to lowest.

```
def Sort_Average1():
    class1=open('Class A.csv', 'r')
    for row in csv.reader(class1, delimiter=','):
        values = (row[1:4])
        valueslist = list(map(int, values))
        av = round(sum(valueslist)/len(valueslist),1)
        print(row[0],av)
```

(Class A.csv is an Excel File and this is where all the results from the students are stored form the quiz)
So in summary, I want, my code to sort results Average from highest to lowest.

Comment: How does this csv file look like?

Comment: Have you tried loading the file into a list and [sorting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) it?

Comment: http://imgur.com/7i7M6yj This is the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Just record the average results you're getting and do a sort.

```
import operator
import csv
import math

def Sort_Average1(csv_file):
    score = {}
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as class1:
        for row in csv.reader(class1, delimiter=','):
            results = map(float, row[1:5])

            # for the floor of average
            floor = math.floor(sum(results)/len(results))

            # for the round of average
            rounding = round(sum(results)/len(results))

            # for the true average
            av = sum(results)/len(results)
            print(row[0],av)

            # row[0] is the student's id
            # score[student's id] = average
            score[row[0]] = av

    # this will do a sort on score from large to small
    sorted_score = sorted(score.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    # return a list of tuples sorted by the score
    return sorted_score

print Sort_Average1("Class A.csv")
>>> ('Tyrone', 4.5)
>>> ('Hrabia', 6.0)
>>> ('Patrishka', 6.75)
>>> ('FilFrank', 2.5)
>>> ('Kacper', 7.5)
>>> [('Kacper', 7.5), ('Patrishka', 6.75), ('Hrabia', 6.0), ('Tyrone', 4.5), ('FilFrank', 2.5)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are 5 quizes results inside the Excel File, not 1. So thank you Rick for the answer, but it manipulates only 1 users scores, not the whole 5.

Comment: Please provide an example of the csv file.

Comment: http://imgur.com/7i7M6yj This is one of my Excel Files. There are 2 more but they are the same, the names and scores just arent the same.

Comment: I've edited the answer. According to your sample csv, it should correctly output the sorted list `[('Kacper', 7.5), ('Patrishka', 6.75), ('Hrabia', 6.0), ('Tyrone', 4.5), ('FilFrank', 2.5)]`

Comment: In this case, I use the float average to get the result. You can also use other techniques like floor or round to get the average as I showed in the answer.

Comment: unfortunately, there is a syntax error on "print Sort_Average1("Class A.csv")".